# How can the proxy address be made as the ONLY point of access to MySQL server for specific user?

Tags: mysql, mysql-proxy

As we know **mysql-proxy** can be used as make a proxy address for MySQL server and also to change any query or results using lua script.

My question is how can I make the proxy address as the ONLY point of access to MySQL server and so if a client tries to communicate with server directly gets a ACCESS DENIED. i.e

> authentication fail if direct access and success if through proxy.

Is it possible to do so only using MYSQL server and mysql-proxy or I MUST go for some third part software?

Thank You

Comment: Simply by using a firewall before the MySQL server or by using the internal permission handling in that server.

Comment: Put mysql=proxy on a server and only allow user access from that ip

Comment: Thanks, Both are good ideas but that will be applicable to all, I don't' want all users get this access denied. for example I want admin to have direct access to MySQL at all the time from any place and other users get access denied if query rather than proxy.